# how to start a docker container with multi interface?

Tags: docker, networking

I want to start a docker container with three interfaces, all these interfaces will be attached to a bridge on host.
    The only solution is providing my own network plugin. the below interface will be invoked by docker daemon once container is created to configure its network:

```
func (d *Driver) Join(r *dknet.JoinRequest) (*dknet.JoinResponse, error)
```

but there is only one `Endpoint` object in `JoinRequest` struct, so the above invocation can only configure one container interface.

I don't know how to create and configure three container interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it multiple time

```
$ docker network create net1
bdc53c143e89d562761eedfd232620daf585968bc9ae022ba142d17601af6146

$ docker network create net2
d9a72a7a6ee6b61da3c6bb17e312e48888807a5a8c159fd42b6c99d219977559

$ docker network create net3
d2be9628f4fd60587d44967a5813e9ba7c730d24e953368b18d7872731a9478c

$ docker run -it --network net3 ubuntu:16.04 bash

root@cd70c7cbe367:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
90: eth0@if91: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:18:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.24.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now your container is running with `net3` network only. You can attach `net1` and `net2` as well.

```
$ docker network connect net1 cd70c7cbe367
$ docker network connect net2 cd70c7cbe367
```

After that check in container

```
root@cd70c7cbe367:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
90: eth0@if91: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:18:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.24.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
92: eth1@if93: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:16:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.22.0.2/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
94: eth2@if95: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:17:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.23.0.2/16 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

PS: the ip command is missing by default in container, so i installed the `iproute2` packaged to check